# time efficient pymongo query for fetching thousands of records and appending it to the list for falsk rest api

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, flask-restful

I have hundreds of thousands of records in the collection named "student_details".

using below pymongo query

```
students_info = db.student_details.find()
```

it gives me all the records which is huge.and I don't want any filters there,i mean no where clause.i want to fetch all the records

Now if I am using for loop and appending it to list.

```
def student_information():
    student_list = []
    for student in students_info:
     '''
       in between there are numbers of if else blocks'''
     student_list.append(student)
    return jsonify({"result":student_list})
```

it takes huge number of time which is making the response time very late.

please help me how can I make it time efficient.

Comment: you should put that if condition in query filter so else part would be removed.Or you can use list comprehension which bit faster than loop

Comment: @vipulprajapati I cannot put it on filter as if else condition makes add or deletes some keys in student object  before appending it to list.for same reason I cannot use list compreshension as it will make code lot more complicated and unreadable